# Different MD5 results between CryptoJS and postman

Tags: postman, cryptojs

I have a backend on NodeJs and using [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/) library to create a MD5 for a payment gateway. The payment gateway script on postman is working fine and generating an MD5 which works with the gateway, however when I send it an MD5 generated from the backend it doesn't work.

```
const content = {
    Currency: "EUR",
    AmountDebit: 15.0,
    Invoice: "testinvoice 123",
    Services: {
      ServiceList: [
        {
          Name: "ideal",
          Action: "Pay",
          Parameters: [
            {
              Name: "issuer",
              Value: "ABNANL2A",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

**Backend MD5** for the above content: `487f7b22f68312d2c1bbc93b1aea445b`

**Postman MD5** for the above content: `ed1dac132299837e2b737e3366227ce6`

Same content is being used in postman and backend however i'm getting different results where only the postman works and the other is rejected.

**Code in backend:**

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(content);
console.log(md5.toString());
```

Any ideas why? and will the md5 differ if the content is object or a string?

Comment: your code prints the same thing from node file or postman

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain please.

Comment: i tried your code by creating a js file and also in postman , i am getting same result in both. Are you sure the value of content is same in both cases ?

Comment: 487f7b22f68312d2c1bbc93b1aea445b is the value in both postman and in js file not getting the other hash you mentioned

Comment: Will the md5 differ if the content is object or a string?

Comment: Ofcourse it will be different , try json.stringify(content) you will get a different md5 . It you are getting string then use JSon.parse(content) so that it will be converted to object

Answer (score 0):

In my backend I was using `req.body` which was an object, converting it to a string using `JSON.stringify()` didn't create the same MD5 that works on the payment gateway. However when I used `req.rawBody` everything work great